# How can I try a Cygwin package that I just created?

Tags: cmake, cygwin, package, cpack

I'm a maintainer of a program that I'd might like to propose for inclusion in the Cygwin distribution.

We use CMake so there is a packager available, and it's easy to create a .bz2 package.

Once I've created the package, how can I try it locally? In Linux this can easily be done, but is there a way to use the Cygwin package installer so that it picks up a local package?

I've read [the package contribution documentation](https://cygwin.com/setup.html) and related pages but can't find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CMake Cygwin package generator seems extremely out-of-date. Cygwin hasn't used `.bz2` for some years. This is from a Cygwin-mailing list answer from Adam Dinwoodie:

> Cygwin packages generally use Cygport to define the build process and
>   so forth.  It's more-or-less the equivalent of rpmbuild for RPM
>   packages, and similar tools for other distribution systems.  The
>   documentation for Cygport is at http://cygwinports.github.io/cygport/;
>   if you're using make in a reasonably standard way, most things should
>   Just Work™.
>
> In particular, if you're using Cygport, it'll automatically do things
>   like creating setup.hint files for you.
>
> For testing locally, I find it's simplest to just do `tar -xaC/ -f
>   <tarball>` on the compiled tarballs that Cygport generates.  That
>   doesn't test the dependency management or anything that requires
>   post-install scripts, but it's fine for checking the installation
>   itself works.